# Incomplete Context in Template due to ManyToManyField

Tags: python, django

I have a beginners question, I am trying to debug and understand the reasons why my context is not showing in the template.

I have followed a tutorial to show PDF invoices in the Django Admin but there seems to be something off with my code which I have been battling for a while.

I want help to know what could be wrong with my code.

So, to summarize the issue I have Project where there are 3 models: `Item`, `OrderItem` and `Order`. The `Order` has a Many-to-Many relationship with `OrderItem` and the `OrderItem` has a Foreign Key with `Item`.

In the template, I am trying to loop between the `Order.Items` which is `items = models.ManyToManyField(OrderItem)` but it is not rendering any data.

Here is the models.py

```
class Item(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    price = models.FloatField()

class OrderItem(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                             on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ordered = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    variation = models.ManyToManyField(Variation)

class Order(models.Model):
    items = models.ManyToManyField(OrderItem)
```

Here is the views.py

```
@staff_member_required
def admin_order_pdf(request, order_id):
    order = get_object_or_404(Order, id=order_id)
    html = render_to_string('pdf.html', {'order': order})
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'filename="order_{}.pdf"'.format(Order.id)
    weasyprint.HTML(string=html).write_pdf(response)
    return response
```

here is the url.py

```
    path('admin/order/(<order_id>\d+)/pdf/', views.admin_order_pdf, name='admin_order_pdf')
```

here is the admin.py

```
def order_pdf(obj):
    return mark_safe('<a href="{}">PDF</a>'.format(reverse('core:admin_order_pdf', args=[obj.id])))


order_pdf.short_description = 'Order PDF'
```

Here is the pdf.html template which is only showing as highlighted

```
                    Ordered on: {{order.ordered_date}}  <----------Showing
                    
                    {% for order_item in order.items.all %}
                    {{ order_item.item.title }}         <----------Not Showing why ?????
                    {% endfor %}
```

My question is since there is for loop `{% for order_item in order.items.all %}` and I use `{{ order_item.item.title }}` why is not showing although I have used the same template in send invoice emails it worked and also the users list and history of orders it is showing.

Just for reference I have used the following code to show users the list of orders with the exact same template. What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it?

What is wrong with using `order = get_object_or_404(Order, id=order_id)` and what should I do different?

```
class OrderSummaryView(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):

        try:
            order = Order.objects.get(user=self.request.user, ordered=False)
            context = {
                'object': order
            }
            return render(self.request, 'order_summary.html', context)
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            messages.warning(self.request, "You do not have an active order")
            return redirect("/")

class OrderList(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = Order
    template_name = "user_orders.html"
    context_object_name = 'orders'
    paginate_by = 2
    ordering = ['-ordered_date']
    queryset = Order.objects.filter(ordered=True).order_by('-ordered_date')

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Order.objects.filter(user=self.request.user, ordered=True).order_by('-ordered_date')
```

Answer (score 1):

In the template, you are iterating over a queryset of **`order_items`**, so each **`order_item`** is an instance of your **`Item`** model.

In the line:

```
{{ order_item.item.title }}
```

you are trying to access the **`item`** attribute of your **`Item`** instance, which doesn't exist.

Missing attributes in django templates render nothing instead of throwing an `AttributeError`, which is why part of the page shows up, instead of a helpful error message.

Change your template to the following, and it should work:

```
{{ order_item.title }}
```

Also, you have what looks to be a typo in your `admin_order_pdf` view.
The line:

```
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'filename="order_{}.pdf"'.format(Order.id)
```

will format the string with the `__str__` method of the **`id`** field, which would look end up looking like this:

```
'filename="order_<django.db.models.query_utils.DeferredAttribute object>.pdf"'
```

This is clearly not what you want.  I think you meant to access the actual **`id`** field of the instance:

```
response['Content-Disposition'] = f'filename="order_{order.id}.pdf"'
```

### Edit:

One more small thing, your urlpattern is incorrect. I'm not sure that it matters in your case, since it appears that your path is working, but this can cause broken code in some cases.  The brackets, **`()`**, are used for regex group matching, but you aren't using a regex path (ie. **`re_path`**).

Instead, you should use a **[`path converter`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/urls/#path-converters)**, for example:

```
path('admin/order/<str:order_id>/pdf/', views.admin_order_pdf, name='admin_order_pdf')
```

Comment: I have tried to `{{ order_item.title }}` didn't work, still nothing is showing